# OpenCL error using Python 3.6 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, driver, python, gpu, opencl

I am trying to use PyOpenCL for the first time on Windows 10 (64 bit) to accelerate some code using my GPU. When trying to `import pyopencl` I get the error:

`File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import pyopencl._cl as _cl
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."`

I am using `Python 3.6.8` and have the `pyopencl 2018.2.5+cl21` package installed.

I have also just installed the latest CUDA toolkit `cuda.10.1.105` and Visual Studio as recommended during the CUDA toolkit installation.

The `OpenCl.dll` file in the `Windows\system32` folder, is the `2.2.1.0 file version`. I checked this by going into Computer Management clicking on my Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 display adaptor.

From other post recommednations, I have tried substituting the `OpenCl.dll` file by others found in my system (see photo) without results. I have then reverted to the original file located in that folder.

[Image for search results of 'OpenCl.dll'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJJxx.png)

I have also downloaded from and installed `pyopencl‑2018.2.5+cl21‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopencl, without success. The error keeps popping up.

I am completely new to OpenCL, CUDA etc. Please forgive me if the error is easy to solve. Thank you for your help and please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: NVIDIA still ships OpenCL version 1.2 with the CUDA toolkit and drivers. Use the `+cl12` wheel or install another OpenCL 2.1 compatible driver, e.g. from Intel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Error stops arising. However, NVIDIA GPU doesn't show as a device, CUDA does show as a platform. I read that, on Linux, this had to do with the NVDIA drivers being in a directory `\Anaconda3\etc\OpenCL\vendors`. This does not exist my Windows Anaconda3 folder. Should it? Any other ideas? Tahnks again for your help. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. It was a bug in my code.

Comment: @Ouroboroski I am facing same problem. I am using spyder with anaconda. I have installed opencCL but it gives error `NoCLPresentError: PyOpenCL must be installed to use OpenCL routines` If you found any solution please guide me

Comment: Did you install PyOpenCL in your environment as well?

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyopencl